# Backbone route with state

Tags: backbone.js, routes, state

Some states are easy to map to routes.  For example:

```
'users/:id'  -->  #users/123
```

The state here is just a simple integer, and so it's quite easy to create a sensible route and pass that state into the route handler.

But what strategy should be used when your state is much more complex (e.g. JSON object, array of arrays, etc.)?

I notice that Gmail "tokenizes" its state in what's seemingly a base-64 encoded token, e.g. something like this:

```
#inbox/h223r488v8vHh4fa9a9qyUTkmb9334mN9O2s8
```

...and then I imagine it somehow reverses that token back into meaningful state, but this process is what I'm confused about.

---

Relevant:  http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/27/the-responsibilities-of-the-various-pieces-of-backbone-js/

Comment: just create a singleton that stores all your tokens and matches them up to whatever json object, etc you want...this could even be a collection of tokens...then when you pull down the token from the route just match it up in the singleton

Comment: @imrane: The states are completely dynamic.  There's no way I could explicitly define them all.

Comment: So this is when `collection` and `model` come into play right? For your email inbox you may have `EmailCollection` which contains multiple `EmailModel` each model is may be referenced to a token (e.g. `h223r488v8vHh4fa9a9qyUTkmb9334mN9O2s8`) or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't get the point! you can create any complex route and handle that! in my own code I use this route `org/:name/prj/:pid/task/:tid/edit` and it works fine! Another one I used is `action/*action` and get the action json from server and handle that json and this works fine too!
Gmail not using token (as far as I know), that gibberish code is id not token

Comment: @KiTO: Your example route is nothing but simplistic values (strings and integers).  Putting aside for the moment that the number of values I need in some cases is well in the dozens, and how impractical it would be to `make/routes/like/this/all/day/long/to/infinity/and/try/to/parse/each/component/out/into/a/route/function/parameter`, I was specifically asking about complex data structures like objects containing other objects and/or arrays.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: @drrcknlsn this complex action is too complex even for human mind! For this example route `action/*complexAction` to a function and then add something like this : `_.each(complexAction.split('-'),function(word){if(isVerb(word))do_magic();else do_another_magic();})` or if complexAction is json then parse it and handle it your own way. I can't see any usecase for something like that! In my current project handle 5-level routes but **everything** is predefined and managed!

Comment: @KiTO: I gave an example use-case with Gmail.  There are tons of potential use-cases for it, though.  Any time you want the user to be able to share/bookmark some particular complex application state, that state needs to be stored in the URL.  Think of a result set for a complex search criteria, for example.  If you want users to be able to bookmark that result set, then the search criteria has to be  embedded in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a base64 javascript library? There are a ton out there. [Here's one](https://gist.github.com/Yaffle/1284012). Pretty sure you'll need to `JSON.stringify` before encoding and `JSON.parse` afterwards.

Then you just decode it if it's already in the URL. Then you don't need to store it, you can just decode and encode.

```
 routes: {
     'encoded/:code': 'decode'
 },
 decode: function(code) {
     // using the linked library
     var decoded = window.atob(code);
     // do what you want
 }
```

base64 is built into some browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding